# Hiding/unhiding an element in HTML with internal page references

Tags: javascript, html, css

Would it be possible to have the internal page reference hide/unhide an element.

```
    <div class="hidden">
    <div id="thanks">
        <h1>Thank you!</h1>
        <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So you would visit "http://www.website.com/#thanks" and the div "hidden" would be hidden / vice versa

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is very vague. Please take the [tour] to see how to best answer a question. Perhaps provide a small example of the HTML you would like to hide/unhide. There are ways to achieve this with CSS which is very dependant on your HTML structure. Otherwise you are using javascript.

Comment: @JonP the question is actually quite clear as long as you know what internal page references are, as I believe that if you don't you wouldn't be able to help with this question.

Comment: @Makaveli can you explain what you mean by internal page reference?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Internal Page Reference is the "#thanks" or whatever the page allows, You can see more at http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/text/internallinks.html

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27179245

Comment: I understand internal links well or as you have chosen to call it an internal page reference. What you had failed to provide was the context and how you wanted to show and hide them, which now appears to via a link. As you chose to insult me. I was trying to assist you to provide a better phrase question. Yet you choose to insult me... nice.

Comment: @JonP I didn't insult you? Sorry if it came across that way, I was using "you" as in anyone not directly directed at you.

Comment: @Makaveli for what it's worth, I didn't know what you meant by "internal page reference," either. I refer to those kinds of links as anchor links or page jumps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide/unhide div with button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203526/hide-unhide-div-with-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the `:target` pseudo class.

```css
#main {
  display: none;  
}
#main:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#main">main</a>

<div id="main">
  main section
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can nest hidden content inside of the `:target` like this.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;  
}
:target .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#main">main</a>

<div id="main">
  <div class="hidden">
    main section
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JavaScript to get the value after hash (#) from a URL.

```
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
```

You can then hide/unhide based on the results.